# How to listen for notification dismissed event in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am listneing to actions pressed for my local notifications, but is there a way to determine when the user dismisses a notification?

Here is how I'm listening to my actions in my AppDelegate, but the dismiss doesn't fire this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        var actionName: String? = nil

        if let identifier = identifier {
            switch identifier {
                case "snoozeAction":
                    actionName = "snoozeActionTapped"
                    break
                default: break
            }

            if let name = actionName {
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(name, object: nil)
            }
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
```

Comment: did you manage to figure it out? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: No I didn't, I gave up and worked around it by hacking a polling method. I just started a bounty to maybe revive it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Apple intentionally makes this hard (impossible?) because the user has explicitly indicated they do not want to interact with your notification.

Comment: Good point. Well my app creates a series of arbitrary notifications that are different every day. I need a way to reschedule notifications if the user hasn't interacted with my app in a long time. Otherwise they'll stop getting notifications because new ones will not be rescheduled.

Comment: Schedule a notification for when they haven't interacted and then unschedule (cancel) it if they interact with the app

Comment: Or alternatively, implement push notifications and send notifications to your users at-will.

Comment: I have to use local for complete offline support. Not sure how I can schedule unless my app is open.

Comment: @TruMan1 I am unsure whether you have tried using this, but `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);` - this removes the observer and you could fire a new NSNotification to alert something that it has occurred.  It's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve from your question; what's the context? What is your app trying to accomplish by dismissing a notification and what do you want to happen as a result?

Comment: @TruMan1, as workaround of your problem "how I can schedule unless my app is open": once user open the app schedule the local notification after x days, if user does not open the app for x days then that already scheduled notification will fire otherwise if user open your app before x days then reschedule your local notification from that day onwards.

Comment: The answer is with `UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier` in iOS 10<=

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dismissing a notification does not wake your application up so there is no way to capture this.

Comment: Well, that's true until iOS 14 (at least). Because now it is executing the `viewDidLoad` and` viewDidAppear` methods of the first `ViewController` of the app

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication!,
            handleActionWithIdentifier identifier:String!,
            forLocalNotification notification:UILocalNotification!,
            completionHandler: (() -> Void)!){

                if (identifier == "FIRST_ACTION"){

                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionOnePressed", object: nil)

                }else if (identifier == "SECOND_ACTION"){
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("actionTwoPressed", object: nil)

                }

                completionHandler()

        }
```