# swift ios check if local notification is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I need to find if user dismissed the notification by clearing from lock screen or closing on notification bar. 
Is there a way to detect it or any handler that would trigger after dismiss?

Comment: Its not possible in iOS to detect whether a notification is getting dismissed in Notification Center.

Comment: Its not possible

Comment: Possible of Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929274/know-if-ios-notification-was-dismiss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096282/what-method-is-triggered-when-local-notification-is-dismissed-from-notification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153519/how-to-listen-for-notification-dismissed-event-in-ios

Comment: Thanks.
And is there a way to hide this clear button on lock screen in iOS 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

I have extensively looked into it and there's no exact way to tell as the notification centre lies outside of app sandbox and apple sends no notification either.

So it's not possible up until now